# Implement FIRST() in select and not in WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to get first value in a field in Oracle when another corresponding field has max value.
Normally, we would do this using a query and a subquery. The subquery ordering by a field and the outer query with `where rownum<=1`.

But, I cannot do this because the table aliases persist only one level deep and this query is a part of another big query and I need to use some aliases from the outermost query.

Here's the query structure

```
select 
(
   select a     --This should get first value of a after b's are sorted desc
   from 
   (
      select a,b from table1 where table1.ID=t2.ID order by b desc
   )
   where rownum<=1
   )
) as "A",
ID
from
table2 t2
```

Now this is not gonna work because alias t2 wont be available at innermost query.

Real world analogy that comes to my mind is I have a table containing records for all employees of a company, their salaries(including past salaries) and the date from which the salary was effective. So, for each employee, there will multiple records. Now, I want to get latest salaries for all the employees.

With SQL server, I could have used `SELECT TOP`. But that's not available with Oracle and since where clauses execute before order by, I cannot use `where rownum<=1` and `order by` in same query and expect correct results.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using your analogy of employees and their salaries, if I understand what you are trying to do, you could do something like this (haven't tested):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
SELECT employee_id, 
       salary, 
       effective_date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY effective_date DESC) rowno
  FROM employees
)
 WHERE rowno=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would much rather see you connect the subquery up with a JOIN instead of embedding it in the SELECT. Cleaner SQL. Then you can use the windowing function  that roartechs suggests.

```
Select t2.whatever, t1.a
From table2 t2
  Inner Join (
    Select tfirst.ID, tfirst.a
    From (
      Select ID, a, 
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition BY ID ORDER BY b DESC) rownumber
      FROM table1
      ) tfirst
    WHERE tfirst.rownumber=1
  ) t1 on t2.ID=t1.ID
```